# Using Helper in view generated by console/shell in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, console, helper, cakephp-2.1

I want to use a custom and the core Html-Helper CakePHP 2.x within an email view generated through the CakePHP console. I am using CakeEmail the normal way but cannot get a grip on how to include helpers.

How do I use/add/include helpers in a view generated through the CakePHP console?

Adding `public $helpers = array('Html');` to the shell doesn't work.

Comment: **Clarification:** Seems like I misinterpreted the errors: the view wasn't missing the helpers, it was missing the base-url. If you find yourself in the situation were you think the Html-Helper doesn't work because the full-url is not returned, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109785/creating-full-url-from-cakephp-2-1-2-console-shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its documented here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-templated-emails

```
$email->helpers(array('Html', 'Custom', 'Text'));
```

Answer (score 2):

For CakePHP 1.3 I did it in a bit dirty way but it works

```
App::import("Core", "Controller");
App::import("Controller", "App");

class SomeShell extends Shell { 

  function startup() { 
    $this->Controller =& new AppController();

    ...
  }
}
```

and AppController uses helpers that I need in my email template. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

This should work in shell (but only in cakePHP below 2.x):

```
App::import('Core', 'Helper');

$html = new HtmlHelper();
```

Comment: you need to also pass a View object